# Get last document from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

so I have an elastic search index and I am sending docs to it attached with a timestamp. I am wondering if there is a way to extract the last document based on the time stamp. I.e. say to elastic give me the doc with the last time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can simply request one single document (`size: 1`) and sorted by decreasing timestamp

```
POST index/_search
{
   "size": 1,
   "sort": { "timestamp": "desc"},
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. I found somewhere else the answer:

GET index-*/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am wondering if there is a way of doing this in using the PHP API.

Comment: Yes, [see this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php#search-for-a-document)

Comment: @devmage feel free to create a new question with your exact needs

Comment: i've already created one , it will be great if you can share your opinion there

Answer (score 2):

A complete `curl` command would look something like this.
Including security options reading user/password from `netrc` and using `cacert`.

```
curl -s \
     --netrc-file ~/.netrc \
     --cacert ~/ca/ca.crt \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     'https://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_search?pretty' \
     -XPOST \
     -d '
         {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": { "@timestamp": "desc"},
            "query": {
               "match_all": {}
            }
        }'
```

The POST request credits go to the answer from @Val

File locations and index names must of course be adapted to your use case. In addition you must know the name of the timestamp field you wish to sort on. It is *usually* `@timestamp` (with the `@`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also make a call with the requested information as parameters:

```
POST /index/_search?size=1&sort=timestamp:desc
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get last document from elasticsearch using java high-level REST client**

> The given solution is in Scala language:

```scala
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.{SearchRequest, SearchResponse}
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders
import org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder

val searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index")
val searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder
val queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()

queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("field.keyword", "field value"))

searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder)
                   .sort("timestamp", SortOrder.DESC)
                   .size(1)
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)
val searchResponse = high_level_client.search(searchRequest)
```

Comment: This is useful to me thank you! One question though if, you're specifying a field value. what if I just wanted to get back the last 5 documents based off the created date field?