# Set filter in Kibana 7/6.7.2 for latest _id in DSL with size 1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want the filter to be set on dashboard which will fetch only latest record

So Used below query in DSL

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is not working in Elasticsearch Kibana 7.0 and I have checked in 6.7.1 also , it is not working

```
"size" : 1 not working
```

The same this works when I post the request in developer tool like

```
POST index/_search
{
   "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

But it does not work in DSL query.
Ref : [Get last document from ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062504/get-last-document-from-elasticsearch?rq=1)

[Return the most recent record from ElasticSearch index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723379/return-the-most-recent-record-from-elasticsearch-index)

When I click on inspect and check the request I get below which does not have my size filter

```
{
  "version": true,
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "12h",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "StartTime": {
      "script": {
        "source": "return doc['timestamp'].value",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    },
    "ExecDurn": {
      "script": {
        "source": "try{\n\tif (doc['endTime'].size() != 0 && doc['timestamp'].size() != 0) {\n\t\tChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(doc['timestamp'].value.toInstant(),doc['endTime'].value.toInstant())\n\t}\n}\ncatch (Exception ignored) {\n}",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    },
    "EndTime": {
      "script": {
        "source": "try{\n\tif (doc['endTime'].size() != 0) {\n\t\tdoc['endTime'].value\n\t}\n\t}\ncatch (Exception ignored) {\n}",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "endTime",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2019-04-06T09:51:57.824Z",
              "lte": "2019-04-21T09:51:57.824Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what's the purpose of having a dashboard to display values from a single document?

Comment: @Val I want to see the latest record in all visualization

Comment: @Val Can you please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Discover view will show 500 records. You can modify that by going to Management > Advanced Settings and changing the "Number of rows" setting to 1.

[image: number of rows]